# Trying to use cell.offset to copy between worksheets where source and destination worksheets have different starting rows

Tags: python, openpyxl, python-3.7

openpyxl has cell module with a property offset:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html

```
offset(row=0, column=0)[source]
Returns a cell location relative to this cell.

Parameters: 
row (int) – number of rows to offset
column (int) – number of columns to offset
Return type:    
openpyxl.cell.Cell
```

I am trying to understand how to use cell.offset (documented above) to copy data from a source worksheet starting at row 2 in column A to a destination sheet starting at row 7 in column A.

I actually can achieve this through the following different approach:

```
row_offset=5
for rows in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=None, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
        ws3.cell(row=cell.row + row_offset, column=1, value=cell.value)
        wb3.save('C:\\folder\\destOutputOffsetby5.xlsx')
```

The above copies data from ws2 starting at row 2 to ws3 starting at row 7 (thanks to the offset of 5).

But I want to use 'cell' module 'offset' property for my own training/learning purposes.

How can I replace above with the offset module?

Here is what I have so far:

```
for row in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=None, min_col=1, max_col=1):    
    for cell in row:
        foo = cell.offset(row=5, column=0)
```

if I then run:

```
"print(foo)"
```

I get the correct offset starting row plus the additional rows (all not shown here):

```
<Cell 'report1570826222449'.A7>
<Cell 'report1570826222449'.A8>
<Cell 'report1570826222449'.A9>
```

and so on.

And if I run

```
print(foo.value)
```

I get the data itself of course:

```
2019-10-03 00:00:00
2019-10-02 00:00:00
```

and so on.

But I can't figure out to copy foo (or foo.value?) from ws2 to ws3. Every approach I try simply ignores cell.offset and writes to destination worksheet column A starting at row2 instead of row 7.

ws3 being:

```
wb3 = load_workbook('C:\\folder\\DetOutPutOffset5.xlsx')
ws3 = wb3['Sheet2']
```

This does not copy any data over as nothing is really changed in ws3.

```
for rows in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=None, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
        cell.offset(row=5, column=0)
        wb3.save('C:\\folder\\Destfile.xlsx')
```

And this:

```
for rows in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=None, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
        ws3.cell.offset(row=5, column=0)
        wb3.save('C:\\folder\\Destfile.xlsx')
```

throws the exception

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'offset'
```

Any suggestions? I feel like I am just missing some basic concept here to bridge the gap between ws2 and ws3. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will not work, because your `ws3.cell` get **not incremented**.

Comment: oh. I am a totally confused python newbie. What might be a use for cell.offset then? I do not understand how to use it I guess. I get that it returns the offset cell (as shown in my print statement) but how might you actually use it? And I am not exactly clear on why ws3.cell can't be "incremented" and how that impacts me as I can print the offset rows as well as their values, which I presumed means it works..

Comment: ***"a use for `cell.offset` then?"***: Reference a `cell` relative from a given `cell`, only **inside the same sheet**. ***"`ws3.cell` can't be \"incremented\""***: I didn't wrote - **can't**, but it's not worth the effort in your case. You have to do: **1:**: init once => `ws3_cell = ws3.cell(row=7...` **2.**: `ws3_cell.value=...` **3.**: `ws3_cell = ws3_cell.offset(row=1...`

Comment: ok well thanks. Still not clear on this or what 'use case' there is for referencing a cell relative to another cell. But sounds like I simply don't grasp how to know that I am barking up the wrong tree with cell.offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will offset the values on ws2 5 rows from ws1's rows:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("copies.xlsx")
ws1 = wb.worksheets[0]
ws2 = wb.worksheets[1]

# Get the row
for rows in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=None, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    # Get the cell
    for cell in rows:
        # offset the values for cells on ws2 with cell offset
        ws2.cell(row=cell.offset(row=5, column=0).row, column=1, value=cell.value)
wb.save("copies_copied.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks @ConSod. I did get this to work as well:
```
row_offset=5
for rows in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=None, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
        ws3.cell(row=cell.row + row_offset, column=1, value=cell.value)
        wb3.save('C:\\folder\\destOutputOffsetby5.xlsx')
```